# xlsread matlab to read data from excel sheet

Tags: matlab

I have data in excel sheet. i can process the raw vlaues in matlab scripts but when i tried to call raw from a function an error has been occuring.

`[~,~, raw] = xlsread('data.xlsx');`
`containsNumbers = cellfun(@isnumeric,raw);`

`raw(containsNumbers) = cellfun(@num2str,raw(containsNumbers),'UniformOutput',false);`

`create_new(state,raw)` % this is my function which is defined as 
 `Function create_new(sate,varargin)`

when i try to process raw values in side a function i get an error.`??? Undefined function or variable "raw".`  Is there any way such that i can  use raw values inside my function?

Comment: First of all, is this really your code? As I see state and one line later it is sate.

Secondly, try to debug the above line by line, and at each line check whether raw exists and whether it is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the complete path of the excel file.  The matlab function will try to open ''data.xlsx' in matlab's curent working directory, not the directory that contains the function.

To create a complete path simply use the function [fullfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html)

```
filePath = fullfile( directoryPath, fileName);
```